# How to color the cell to the left, comparing columns in excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to write a conditional formatting rule in Excel to color a cell (red,yellow,green) if cell in column to the left of it is less, equal or greater. Colored ones should be only column `L` and `O`.

How do I write one formula for both columns `L` and `O`?

[image: Columns]

Comment: You'll need three formulas (one for less than, one for equal, one for greater than), then just apply that to `L` and `O` columns, no? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

To help you out quickly:

Select column L and add these three conditions (as formula)

```
=$L1<$K1 'This should be conditionally formatted as green
=$L1=$K1 'This should be conditionally formatted as yellow
=$L1>$K1 'This should be conditionally formatted as red
```

Do the same for column O

```
=$O1<$N1 'This should be conditionally formatted as green
=$O1=$N1 'This should be conditionally formatted as yellow
=$O1>$N1 'This should be conditionally formatted as red
```

Regards, Jan